# "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" when trying to delete an item from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, random

at the moment, i am trying to create a python application that will take my code, create a list with songs in it. Then create a random question from the randomly chosen questions from the song list. Confusing i know.

This is my code and i hope someone can help. I seem to get the error:

```
'del question[count]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range'.
```

From my understanding i don't think it is out of range and i have spent hours trying to figure it out. This is the code i have:

```
import csv, random

#creating random questions
def random_songs(username):
    songBook = open('songs.csv', 'r')
    con_song = csv.reader(songBook)
    user = open('user_data.csv', 'a')
    con_user= csv.writer(user, delimiter = ',')
    class data():
        songs = []
        count = 0
        song_name = []
        artist_name = []
        song_answer = []
        song_question = []


    #Setting the song name and artist into a list.
    for i in con_song:
        for x in i:
            data.songs.append(x)

    #Splitting up the data from the csv file into song name and artist name.
    for length in range(0, len(data.songs)):
        if data.count % 2 == 0:
            data.song_name.append(data.songs[data.count])
            data.count += 1
        else:
            data.artist_name.append(data.songs[data.count])
            data.count += 1

    #Randomly chosing a song
    for i in range(0, 1):
        number = random.randint(0, len(data.song_name))
        data.song_answer.append(data.song_name[number])
    #Generating the question
    #print(data.song_answer)

    question = []
    for s in data.song_answer:
        question = list(s)
        print(s)
        length_s = int(len(s) -1)
        count = 1
        for i in range(length_s):
            if count <= length_s and count > 1:
                print('good')
                count = int(count)
                del question[count]
                count += 1
            else:
                print('bad')
                count += 1



random_songs('James')
```

Here is the song csv file project on the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LxPlKF0pduXE1_r7WWzlwzMZ0mKeY4yY

I hope, that you can help or this will help you once solved.

Thanks in advance.
    James McCannon

Comment: try replacing `if count <= length_s and count > 1:` by `if count < length_s and count > 1:`. The error shows that the value of count is greater than the number of elements in `question`

Answer (score 0):

Lets improve your loop..

The first for loop seems legit so you can keep that, just remove count

```
for s in data.song_answer:
        questions = list(s)
        print(s)
```

The second for loop can be replaced like this:

```
for question in questions:
        print('good')
         questions.remove(question)
```

We dont need to use range in python you can remove whe iterating. I didnt test this but if questions is a valid list it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What i want to do from here is to take the song name and then remove everything in the name apart from the first letter and last letter. Then if for example the word was 5 letters long i would have 5 dashes in between the word. When i run this code this is the result:                                                                                        
['R', 'I', 'V', 'E', 'R']
['I', 'E']                                                                                                                                               but want is ['R','-','-','-','R']

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a precise idea of what you're trying to do, but hope this will point you in the right direction

```
import csv
import random

class Song:

    def __init__(self, name, artist):
        self.name = name
        self.artist = artist
        self.question = None
        self.answer = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} by {self.artist}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

songBook = open('songs.csv', 'r')
songs = []
for i in songBook:
    # split gives you a list with the two fields
    x = i.split(',')
    songs.append(Song(x[0],x[1]))

for song in songs:
    self.answer = random.choice(songs).name
```